# Display matrix with single line semi-colon delimited format

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I input matrices into Octave like:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
```

Octave outputs them in a different multi-line format:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Can I get Octave to display a matrix with the formatting used for input? In other words, format a matrix with the single line semi-colon delimited format?

Comment: If you want to stick to a numerical format, you can't. The `;` character indicates a new row for the matrix, so that's what Octave outputs the data as. If you are not bothered about the data type and can live with a string representation of the matrix, then @Marcin's answer is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mat2str](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html) will can make string representation of matrix, for example:

```
octave:4> a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
octave:5> mat2str(a)
ans = [1 2 3;4 5 6]
```